# return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to make a free music app and i am trying to put in mp4 video of the music. But the second button just makes it crash with      *`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, 
NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]`*     The code i'm using is

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Under_Control" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

[[self view]addSubview:mpc.view];

[mpc setFullscreen:YES];

[mpc play];
```

And also put

*{
 `MPMoviePlayerController *mpc;` 
}*

Under  *`@interface ViewController;`*

Comment: It only crashes when i have clicked the button. But when a click a different button it plays the music just fine.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and it seems the URL is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

A crash in that location simply means there was an uncaught exception somewhere in your code. Adding an exception breakpoint in Xcode ([Exception breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)) will make the program crash on the line that is throwing the exception.

Edit: another thought, are you getting a valid URL variable back? I'm guessing that passing `nil` to the MPMoviePlayerController is the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, check to make sure that you don't have duplicate referencing outlets that you hooked up, or referencing outlets that shouldn't be there anymore that don't have matching methods in your code anymore.

[image]